# Is 'for' required in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, parallelism, for

Is the for needed in the sentence below, and if so why?

The law currently prevents terminally ill patients to choose death and **for** physicians to aid them

The law currently prevents terminally ill patients to choose death and physicians to aid them

Comment: Why do you think it belongs, or doesn't belong there? Also, what is the source of that sentence? It doesn't seem grammatical either way. (*allow* can optionally link with *for*, but *prevent* links with *from*, if anything, and doesn't take a to-infinitive)

Comment: Should be **prevents patients from choosing death and physicians from aiding them**, or **forbids patients to choose death and physicians to aid them**.

Comment: It doesn't stop patients (or anyone else) from choosing death, just stops people helping them.

Comment: 'It is _illegal_ **for** patients to choose death, and **for** physicians to help them' would work, except as I said, suicide is not illegal in most countries, much less contemplating it.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is wrong both with and without the for. You prevent someone *from* doing something, not *to* doing it.

It's also ambiguous. Does "choose death" means something like "refuse treatment" or is it a reference to suicide? Presumably physicians can aid patients with pain reduction, but can't help them die.

I suspect that the context is the illegality of assisted suicide. If so, make that clear.

Comment: euthanasia is obviously the subject and it is not suicide if aided.

Comment: @Brad Yes, that's what I should have said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Q. **Is the "for" needed in the sentence below, and if so why?**

The law currently prevents terminally ill patients to choose death and **for** physicians to aid them

---

I would suggest the text is not related to suicide but euthanasia. In which case in most countries it is illegal for both patients and others including physicians to take part in such an activity. I also suggest that "**for**" is required as in this case it emphasis the wrong doing by both patients and physicians. It also makes clear that the patient is still responsible if not aided by a physician but by others (possibly a family member).

**euthanasia**; noun [ U ]; the act of killing someone who is very ill or very old so that they do not suffer any more: [Ref CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/euthanasia?q=-)

---

**Note**

> The infinitive of a verb has two forms: the to-infinitive and the infinitive without to. The to-form consists of to plus the base form of the verb:

**choose**; verb; to decide what you want from two or more things or possibilities: [Ref CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/choose)

*She had **to choose** between the two men in her life.*

Comment: " I also suggest that "for" is required as in this case it emphasis the wrong doing by both patients and physicians. " - which part of the sentence does this distinction apply to exactly? All I see is an ungrammatical use of *?prevent for*.

Comment: prevent for? where did that come from? IF the use of "for" is incorrect in the above sentence is it also incorrect in the following and why? "It is not right **for a physician to** turn a research patient into a source of personal profit."  Ref: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/physician.html#/

Comment: If you do not have "for" or some other word to split the sentence and hence show (emphasis) that there are two responsible parties. Then, it arguably reads as if "The law currently prevents terminally ill patients to choose death **when** physicians aid them"

Comment: I don't agree with your interpretation. *The law prevents terminally ill patients from choosing death and physicians from aiding them* still has an *and*, not a *when*, making the two clauses independent. *?prevent for* came from OP's example sentence - *\*The law prevents... (and) for physicians...*. Your example sentence is fine, *it **is right** for me to do X* is valid, *\*it **prevents** for me to do X* is not, the two have different valence.

Comment: You could rephrase OP's sentence to use *for NOUN* (something like "The law currently prevents terminally ill patients from choosing death and for physicians, it prevents them from aiding them (the patients)"), but it's not required for the sentence to make sense.

Comment: @Maciej Stackowski: from choosing death and physicians from aiding them still has an and, not a when, making the two clauses independent.**agreed* hence my "Then, it arguably reads as if..." Also your injecting prevents actually helps me "ill patients from choosing death and for (preventing) physicians aiding them,

Answer (score 0):

> The law currently prevents terminally ill patients to choose death and for physicians to aid them.

> The law currently prevents terminally ill patients to choose death and physicians to aid them.

From Google Dictionary, the preposition should be *from* rather than *to*.

> prevent

> verb
> verb: prevent; 3rd person present: prevents; past tense: prevented; past participle: prevented; gerund or present participle: preventing
> 1.
> keep (something) from happening.

I rephrase the 2nd example.

> The law currently prevents terminally ill patients [from choosing] death and physicians [from aiding] them.

A longer form show that placement of *for* at any of the 2 locations does not comply with parallelism, and hence both sentences below are unusual.

> The law currently prevents terminally ill patients from choosing death and *for* prevents physicians from aiding them. [Illustrates wrong use of *for*]

> The law currently prevents terminally ill patients from choosing death and prevents *for* physicians from aiding them.  [Illustrates wrong use of *for*]